# Unresolved external symbol for NtResumeProcess

Tags: c++, winapi, sspi

I am developing software which must log in to an Active Directory with the following credentials:

1. Username
2. Domain Name
3. NTLM password

This is my code:

```
if (OpenProcessToken(process_infos.hProcess, TOKEN_READ | (is_impersonate ? TOKEN_DUPLICATE : 0), &handle_token))
{
    if (GetTokenInformation(handle_token, TokenStatistics, &token_status, sizeof(token_status), &needed_size))
    {
        NtResumeProcess(process_infos.hProcess);
    }
}
```

After successful authentication, it should run a process with the authenticated token. However, in the program, I wanted to use NtResumeProcess, but when I use it, the compiler gives me the following error:

> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "long __cdecl
>   NtResumeProcess(void *)" (?NtResumeProcess@@YAJPEAX@Z) referenced in
>   function "void __cdecl Dispatcher(void)" (?Dispatcher@@YAXXZ)

How should I resolve this problem?

Comment: NtResumeProcess is an undocumented API so you'll need to find out which library it lives in

Comment: Looks like you need to load it yourself using GetProcAddress: https://github.com/xilun/cbwin/blob/master/outbash/ntsuspend.cpp

Comment: at first you wrong declare `NtResumeProcess`- must me *extern "C"* and *__stdcall* aka `NTAPI` or `WINAPI`. at second - link with *ntdll.lib* or *ntdllp.lib*

Comment: @AlanBirtles -nothing need to *load*

Comment: Try linking to ntdll.lib

Comment: anyway i not understand - for what you need `NtResumeProcess`

Comment: @RbMm Thank you, brother. I use extern "C" and my problem is fixed now. The program compiled successfully.

Comment: @RbMm In mimikatz project which I used it for my study, It uses this api.

Comment: *It uses this api* - this not mean that you must do this. you must understand what you doing and for what